# Fitnesse - Standard fitSharp configuration problem with .NET 4

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitsharp

I have been using Fitnesse.NET for some time and am now attempting to upgrade to the newer fitSharp engine. I immediately ran into a roadblock though. Starting with a fresh system, I downloaded the latest fitnesse.jar and executed/installed it; all my test pages were then displaying fine from my browser.

The issue arises when I add configuration for fitSharp to the root page. I tried a variety of combinations of setting TEST_RUNNER and COMMAND_PATTERN; the end result was always that, upon executing any test, the fitnesse server never returned a result to my browser. For reference here is my root content, confirming these variable definitions are present and correct, at least according to this fitSharp [configuration page](http://fitsharp.github.com/Fit/UsingFitnesse.html):

```
variable defined: TEST_RUNNER=fitSharp\RunnerW.exe 
variable defined: COMMAND_PATTERN=%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,fitSharp\fit.dll %p
```

I finally found one [troubleshooting note](http://www.asoftwarecraft.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-with-fitsharp-and.html) mentioning that RunnerW gives some diagnostic information so I switched to that and received this error message, indicating it is apparently an issue arising due to .NET 4:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\fitnesse\fitSharp\fit.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies.  Operation
>   is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515) File name:
>   'file:///c:\fitnesse\fitsharp\fit.dll'
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException:  An attempt was made to load an assembly
>   from a network location which would
>   have caused the assembly to be
>   sandboxed in previous versions of the
>   .NET Framework. This release of the
>   .NET Framework does not enable CAS
>   policy by default, so this load may be
>   dangerous. If this load is not
>   intended to sandbox the assembly,
>   please enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569
>   for more information.

The referenced MSDN page says that I need this in my config file:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

So it looks like I have three possibilities. Is there:

1. An app.config or equivalent where I can insert that config section?
2. A way to stop fitnesse from thinking that my local file is on a remote path?
3. A way to enable CAS policy for the .NET framework?

Suggestions would be appreciated!

*2010.01.17 Edit:* I am using fit protocol rather than slim protocol in my environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen that before! Why does it think C: is a 'dangerous' network location? Anyway, the executable is Runner.exe (or RunnerW.exe) so if you create a Runner.exe.config with the settings above, it should pick it up.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, that succeeded. But then I ran smack into another issue that has apparently reared its head before: type DoFixture is not found (this is fitsharp v1.8 for .net 4.0). I will enter this as a separate question when I get a chance--unless you have a quick answer!

Comment: It's a bug - being fixed. Workaround is to add namespace fitlibrary to suite config file.

Comment: Can you clarify the fix for "DoFixture"?  I don't understand what to do.  Thank you

Comment: Create a suite config file http://fitsharp.github.com/FitSharp/SuiteConfigurationFile.html with something like this in it: <suiteConfig>
    <ApplicationUnderTest>
        <addNamespace>fitlibrary</addNamespace>
    </ApplicationUnderTest>
</suiteConfig>

Answer (score 10):

I know this has been answered but, imho there is a better resolution.  If you 'unblock' fit.dll (right-click->properties->Unblock) you won't get the error.  Happens due to downloaded files being locked by default.

Answer (score 0):

visit this page

http://oweng.net/Visual-Studio-2010/Coded-UI-Fitnesse/integrating-coded-ui-and-fitnesse-fitsharp-slim-1.aspx

i was facing a similar issue but got resolved after visiting tjis page.